# How to resize graph to fixed dimensions in matplotlib animation

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am wanting to plot two list in real time using matplotlib animation, with the help of the community I was able to plot my graph. I am now wanting to simplify my real time animation a bit as well as re-structure my graph.

Here are my objectives:

1. Plot x-axis: length of list "my_average"
2. Plot y-axis: elements in list "my_average"
3. y-axis limit -1 to 1 (all my elements in list "my_average" are between -1 and 1)

I do not know what I am doing wrong with my code thus far:

```
class StdOutListener(StreamListener):
    def on_data(self, data):
        json_load = json.loads(data)
        texts = json_load['text'] # string
        #print(texts)

        #drop zero in list
        if 0 in my_list: my_list.remove(0)  
        #print    




        #calculate average
        average = numpy.mean(my_list)
        b = my_average.append(average)
        print "average =", my_average



    def __init__(self):
      self.start_time = time.time()
      self.x = [len(my_average)]
      self.y = [my_average]
      self.my_average = []
      self.line_actual, = plot(self.x, self.y)                  # line stores a Line2D we can update
      self.line_average, = plot(self.x, self.my_average)       # line stores a Line2D we can update


    def on_data(self, new_value):
     time_delta = time.time() - self.start_time                # on our x axis we store time since start
     self.x.append(time_delta)
     self.y.append(new_value)
     self.my_average.append(numpy.mean(self.y))
     self.line_actual.set_data(self.x, self.y)
     self.line_average.set_data(self.x, self.my_average)
     ylim([min(self.y), max(self.y)])        # update axes to fit the data
     xlim([0, max(self.x)])
     draw()                                  # redraw the plot

ion()                                       # ion() allows matplotlib to update animations.

out_listener = StdOutListener()
for i in range(10000):
  out_listener.on_data(i + numpy.random.randint(-5,5))
```

Thank you in Advance

Comment: Is there a specific reason why you posted ~20 empty lines in your code?Please format your code properly.

Comment: Is there a question?

Comment: @hitzg Sorry for the extra spaces they have been removed. 

The question is, how can i resize this graph to have fixed y-axis limits (-1, 1) and for my X-axis how can I plot the length of the list.

Comment: Also, for the next time, your code should have proper indentation (since this is relevant in python). But as your example was not executable (which it should be --> [link](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)) anyways, it does not really matter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So:

1. I'm not sure what you mean by *plot length of the list*. But I assume you want to create an index array with indices from 0 to `len(my_average)`. That is what `range` is for:

   ```
   self.x = range(len(my_average))
   ```
2. You already use the `ylim` function, which does exactly what you want. But instead of passing the min/max of your data you just have to pass your desired static values:

   ```
   ylim(-1, 1)
   ```